# Why are binary search index computed this way?

Tags: algorithm, binary, mean, binary-search

In every code piece I read online or on book, say if someone wants to compute the midpoint between s and e, they do:

```
int mid = s + ((e - s) / 2);
```

Mathematically isn't this the same thing as

```
int mid = (s + e) / 2;
```

So why is it written in the first way often? My guess is to prevent integer overflow but not sure.

Thanks

Comment: You've gotten the right answer. In fact, some code does use `(s+e)/2`, but yes, it can lead to problems with integer overflow.

Comment: They are not the same due to how division of integers occurs.

Comment: @EdHeal  The problem is just overflow.  The rounding in the division works out the same as long as `s` and `e` are positive.

Comment: @EdHeal: Can you specify some numbers (that don't lead to overflow) that produce different results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If e is close to the maximum value for an integer, then `(s+e)/2` can overflow, but `s+(e-s)/2` cannot (assuming that `s` is nonnegative).

For example `(MAX_INT-2 + MAX_INT)` == `-4`, so `(MAX_INT-2 + MAX_INT)/2` == `-2`